# Does VSCode have a key/command to move cursor to first/last line of screen?

Tags: visual-studio-code

(Running 1.21.1 on OS X 10.12.6)

I found a reference to this ability elsewhere on SO, but the keystroke given scrolls the screen up/down one line, it doesn't move the cursor to the top/bottom of the screen. Maybe it's different on Windows than Mac?

I've searched for "top" or "first" or "screen" in both Keyboard Shortcuts and the keybindings file itself, but I don't see anything.

I'm either missing something (probable), or I'm not searching for the right words. What is the key and/or command for this?

Comment: Your answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51554277/how-can-i-configure-ctrlpgup-and-ctrlpgdown-keybindings-in-vscode-navigate-to/51554508#51554508  Not a duplicate though to aid searchability.

Answer (score 5):

In Windows the default keybindings are <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>End</kbd>.

The Command are `cursorTop` and `cursorBottom`. I am not sure in OSX, but the command should be the same.

Comment: cursorTop/Bottom position to the top/bottom of the *file*, not the *screen*. On the Mac they are assigned to cmd-Up/Down (most Windows Ctrl-keys turn into Cmd-keys on the Mac).

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio, ctrl + shift + page up / page down will move cursor to top and down of the screen with selection.

Comment: No, it doesn't. And even if it did, I don't want selection, I just want to move the cursor. Removing the "shift" and just using cmd+pageUp/Down doesn't do the right thing, either.