# How can I configure Ctrl+PgUp and Ctrl+PgDown keybindings in vscode navigate to the top/bottom of the view instead of switching tabs?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keymapping

By default, Ctrl+PageUp and Ctrl+PageDown combinations in Visual Studio Code switch view to the next/previous tab. I would like to reconfigure them so they work like in Visual Studio, so they navigate to the top/bottom of the screen.

I am trying to modify the editor's keybindings (keybindings.json) but I find myself unable to find proper commands.

So far, I have found:

- cursorTop/cursorBottom - moves cursor to the top/bottom of the whole file
- scrollLineUp/scrollLineDown - scrolls the view, but does not change cursor's position
- scrollPageDown/scrollPageUp - moves the view one page down/up, but does not change the cursor's position

I have tried Visual Studio Keymap (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.vs-keybindings) extension, but it also does not provide the required functionality.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of course, almost immediately after posting a question I've stumbled upon a solution. This issue comments (https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/15058) gave me a hint, so I tried *cursorMove* command with *"to": "viewPortTop"* and *"to": "viewPortBottom"* arguments and, surprisingly, it worked.

The complete json to be added to *keybindings.json* is:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+pageup",
    "command": "cursorMove",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "args": {
        "to": "viewPortTop"
    }
}    ,
{
    "key": "ctrl+pagedown",
    "command": "cursorMove",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "args": {
        "to": "viewPortBottom"
    }
}
```

Comment: For interesting things you can do with cursorMove and select, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50838602/bind-a-keypress-to-a-shell-command-that-uses-the-current-file-in-visual-studio-c/50846586#50846586 [type and select text to run in terminal].

Comment: With Ctrl+PgDown this also scrolls the editor one line down. Probably because the last partially visible line is selected instead of the last fully visible line. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: See, the same happens to me, too. The `"to": "viewPortBottom"` parameter needs an additional `"value": 2` to avoid the downscrolling. It might not move the cursor the the very last line in all cases, but it shouldn't scroll. Moving to the top doesn't need this, it always jumps to the first fully visible line. They probably only consider a line's top position, not both top and bottom.

Comment: This is seriously awesome info - been searching for this off and on for years. I've used this for years coding and I've not had it in vccode for the past few years and I find myself trying to use it. I can't stand Visual Studio 2022 much - vccode just works so much better. Anyway, thanks.