# Make VS Code emulate visual studio's ctrl pageUp to move cursor to top of view

Tags: visual-studio-code

Using visual studio, ctrl+PageUp moves the cursor to the top if the current view.  This is very different from PageUp: if the cursor is in the middle of the view vertically, PageUp will scroll up a page; ctrl+PageUp won't scroll at all, it will simply move the cursor to the top-most visible line.

Searching VS Code's keyboard shortcuts, I don't see anything like this.  Am I wrong?

Comment: There is no built-in command to do that, but see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51554277/how-can-i-configure-ctrlpgup-and-ctrlpgdown-keybindings-in-vscode-navigate-to for how to do it.

Comment: Thanks, this is duplicate; my search was poor (I searched "ctrl PageDown" instead of "Ctrl+PgDown")